# Error reporting only once

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm writing some code which handles a lot of data. When an error occures, it usually happens that the error will occur many times, so I want to report it only once. The problem I have is, that I want to have individual error messages. In `C` I would use a method with variadic arguments, bit of course this is not really typesafe, so I wonder how I can achieve the same in C++ with typesafe output. I know that I can `stringstream` and create the indvidual string, but that would mean that I have to create the full error message, even if it is discarded, because it was already printed, and stringstream is not exactly fast either.

So currently I use code like this:

```
    std::string key = "BT:EMPTY";
    if(mErrorReport.find(key) == mErrorReport.end())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR [" << Name<< "] Type is empty! " << std::endl;
        mErrorReport.insert(key);
    }

    std::string key = "UI:"+Unitcode;
    if(mErrorReport.find(key) == mErrorReport.end())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR [" << Name<< "] Room with the id " << Unitcode << " doesn't exist! " << std::endl;
        mErrorReport.insert(key);
    }

    ...
```

In C I would have written a variadic function like this:

```
 void ErrorLog(const char *key, int nLogLevel, const char fmt, ...)
 {
      // Check if this error was already reported before.
      if(mErrorLog.find(key) == mErrorLog.end())
      {
          fprintf(stderr, fmt, ...);
          mErrorLog.insert(key);
      }
 }
```

So I wonder if there is some best practice for something like that.

Comment: I am really unsure what you are trying to do exactly, but if the question is about type-safe ellipsis functions in C++, they do exist in a form of a variadic template functions. If you elaborate a bit, I'd be able to provide more tailored answer.

Comment: I updated an example how I would have done it in C (pseudo code).

Comment: *"When an error occures, it usually happens that the error will occur many times"* - am I the only one who thinks that a violation of the Fail Fast principle seems to be the real problem here?

Comment: I'm processing a huge dataset, and we ignore such errors and the result for that record is discarded, but they must be reported anyway. This is not an error condition which should completely stop the code.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, fail fast has it limit. I hate programms which report errors one by one - each time requiring you to re-run it. A good error reporting (a compiler, for instance) tries to report as many errors as it can within a single run.

Comment: @SergeyA: Well, but suppressing errors like the OP intends to does not exactly sound like "report as many errors as it can within a single run". Quite the opposite.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I don't need to report a unique error thousands of time. And I certainly can't stop production for several days just because there is one record wrong...

Comment: @Devolus: Since I don't know anything about your system, there's not much more I can say about this. However, generally, I think there is a huge difference between 1 unique error and 1000 unique errors, and I wonder if your users (or developers / testers) would be happy about the fact that the system hides this difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use

```
void ErrorLog(const std::string& key, const std::string& name, const std::string& what)
{
    if (mErrorLog.find(key) == mErrorLog.end())
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR[" << name << "]" << what << std::endl;
        mErrorLog.insert(key);
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
ErrorLog("BT:EMPTY", Name, "Type is empty!");
ErrorLog("UI:" + Unitcode, Name, std::string("Room with the id ") + Unitcode + " doesn't exist!");
```

If `Name` doesn't change you could remove the parameter and just add it to the `std::err` call.

**Update:** Alternative solution

```
class ErrorLogWriter
{
public:

    ErrorLogWriter(const std::string& name, const std::string& key, std::set<std::string>& log)
        :m_name(name)
        , m_key(key)
        , m_log(log)
    {}

    ErrorLogWriter& operator<<(const std::string& msg)
    {
        if (m_log.find(m_key) == m_log.end())
        {
            std::cerr << "ERROR[" << m_name << "]" << msg << std::endl;
            m_log.insert(m_key);
        }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::string m_key;
    std::set<std::string>& m_log;
};

class ErrorLog
{
public:

    ErrorLog(const std::string& name, std::set<std::string>& log)
        :m_name(name)
        ,m_log(log)
    {}

    ErrorLogWriter operator()(const std::string& key)
    {
        return ErrorLogWriter(m_name, key, m_log);
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::set<std::string>& m_log;
};

int main()
{
    std::string Name = "NAME";
    std::string Unitcode = "UNITCODE";
    std::set<std::string> mErrorLog;

    ErrorLog log(Name, mErrorLog);

    log("BT:EMPTY") << "Type is empty!";
    log("UI:" + Unitcode) << "Room with the id " << Unitcode << " doesn't exist!";
}
```

Comment: You can even test `insert` result to do the look-up only once.

Comment: Guess I was thinking to complicated, but along with std::to_string() this is a good solution.